# Replace macro value while using as member variable's template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, macros

#### A glimpse of system

After declaration of macro system use that as a template parameter to instantiate an object of a class. Later, that template parameter will be translated to 0 or -1 using sort of CMake operation.

#### Previous approach

- As like as usual way, right now macros are defined and object's are created outside of the class/function. it is working perfectly.
- The way of setting value for Macro are doing from a `ini` file which is not accessible from my perspective. CMake is designed which is so far not modifiable. Everything works fine
- An example of present approach:

  - consider, file name is `math.cpp`

  ```cpp
  #ifndef MATH
  #define MATH
  #endif
  LOG<MATH> math("file_name.txt"); // Constructor of LOG<MATH> requires a file name explicitly
  #undef  MATH

  class Do_Math
  {
    public:
      Do_Math(){}
      virtual ~Do_Math(){}

      void Process()
      {
        math.Write(2); // Write is a function of LOG<MATH> class
      }
  };
  ```
- Here, the class template `LOG<MATH>` will work only for `LOG<0>` or `LOG<-1>`.
- To do the translation of `MATH` in a `dbg.ini` file the following is written

  ```bash
  [math.cpp]
  MATH = ON
  ```
- Working method of `dbg.ini` file is defined in a dedicated CMake file.

#### Required Approach/ My goal:

- The present way has a problem that it is not dealing as OOP and to use the object every time has to write is separate files where they will be used
- So, idea is to shift those objects as a class member and later this new class will be inherited by others who requires
- I have planned to shift the object declaration using macros as a protected member of the new class
- So far what I have done

  - Created a new class only to declare the object of `LOG<MATH>` as like as follows
  - Consider the file name `log_dbg.h`

  ```cpp
  class LOG_DBG
  {
    public:
      LOG_DBG():math("file_name.txt"){}
      virtual ~LOG_DBG(){}
    protected:
      #ifndef MATH
      #define MATH
      #endif
      LOG<MATH> math;
      #undef  MATH
  };
  ```
- Now, include and inherit this in math.cpp file

  ```cpp
  #include "log_dbg.h"
  class Do_Math : public LOG_DBG
  {
    public:
      Do_Math(){}
      virtual ~Do_Math(){}

      void Process()
      {
        math.Write(2); // Write is a function of LOG<MATH> class
      }
  };
  ```
- Right now, still I am using `dbg.ini` file only changed the file path which was there as `[log_dbg.h]`

#### Issue

- Right now, I can compile the code and pretty sure that, `main.cpp` has also no problem with the object `math`. But, right now the `dbg.ini` file cannot place `ON` onto the macro name what was done at Previous approach. That's why `math.Write(2);` line is not executing. Because, the default class template is `LOG<-1>` where all functions are undefined. So, if have to work class template should be translated to `LOG<0>`. And this conversion from `MATH` to `0` is doing by `dbg.ini` file where that macro name is set to `ON`. And `ON` will turn to `0` using CMake function.
- I believe that, pre-processor is compiled correctly but not confident that the replacement of value is doing from `dbg.ini`file or not.

Is there any steps where I am doing it incorrectly? Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing log4cpp categories, except at compile time.

Comment: I don't recommend this kind of design where you pull logging into your code directly. Logging is infrastructure that you don't want to pull into your (unit testable) classes. If I have a class that needs to log or report something create an abstract base class with "report" methods and then inject that into the class that needs to do the reporting (e.g. your Do_Math class). The nice thing is now you can make ANY kind of logging implementation independently (including something like you are trying to do). And for unit testing you can inject an implementation that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer but what is the issue with my current approach? As far I have understood, preprocessor will create the variable without paying attention whether it is declared globally or encapsulated. And my current system also can set/replace the value of macro if the macros are declared globally. But, in present case while macors are declaring as member variable system cannot set the value.

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to use those macros at all your cpp file should be compiled once.  So the whole #ifdef... #endif is not needed. And you can't move (should not move) the variable to a header file (not even with the macros). You do know using global variables is not recommended right?

Comment: Unclear to me how `MATH` is defined. wonder if your issue is a missing build dependency so that when dbg.ini file is modified, your project is not rebuild...

Comment: @Jarod42 after declaring by pre-processor MATH is defined using CMAKE functions. A logic is written which check the dbg file and check whether the MACRO value is set `ON` or `OFF`. If `ON` during compiel time that value is set to `0`. So, `MATH -> ON -> 0` this flow is happened. System is building properly and worked(mentioned in question) while this maco stuffs are written globally. But as  a member variable it is not working

Comment: You might get rid of CMake/dbg.ini stuff in the question and just write `#define MATH 0`... But I suppose that it would not produce the error (as you cannot get `MATH`==`-1`). So I suppose that your CMake rule is wrong/incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean in code :

```
#include <iostream>

// do not declare a generic log interface
// you will not know what the log infrastructure will
// need and what its capabilities are/will be (in the future)
class math_reporting_itf
{
public:
    virtual ~math_reporting_itf() = default;
    virtual void report_process(int value) const noexcept = 0; // reporting should never throw!
};

// An implementation of a logger (this one logs to std::cout)
class math_dbg_logger_t :
    public math_reporting_itf
{
public:
    math_dbg_logger_t() // todo open file etc.
    {
    }

    void report_process(int value) const noexcept override
    {
        // write to file, a database, a network logger whatever
        std::cout << "Math Process (" << value << ")\n";
    }
};

class Do_Math 
{
public:

    Do_Math(const math_reporting_itf& reporting) :
        m_reporting{ reporting }
    {
    }

    void Process()
    {
        // math.Write(2); // Write is a function of LOG<MATH> class
        m_reporting.report_process(2);
    }

private:
    const math_reporting_itf& m_reporting;
};

int main()
{
    math_dbg_logger_t logger;
    Do_Math math{logger};
    math.Process();
    return 1;
}
```